# How to detect where data is lost when multithreading is used

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I have a program that enables multiple threads to insert entries into a hashtable and retrieve them. The hashtable itself is a very simple implementation with a struct defining each bucket entry and a table (array) to hold each bucket. I'm very to new to concurrency and multithreading, but I think that in order to avoid data from being lost in the table during insert and read operations, some kind of synchronization (in the form of something like mutex locking) needs to be added to avoid preemption on one process's data operation by another's.

In practice though, I'm not really sure how to tell where a process could be preempted in either a data read or write operation on the hashtable and where exactly locks should be placed to avoid such problems as well as dead locks. As per [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/) website, for the hashtable insert method, I added a mutex lock before each key gets inserted into the table and unlock it at the end of the function. I essentially do something similar in the function where I'm reading data from the hash table and when I run the code, it seems that the keys are successfully being inserted initially, but the program hangs when the keys are supposed to be retrieved. Here is how I implemented the locking for each function:

```
// Inserts a key-value pair into the table
void insert(int key, int val) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    int i = key % NUM_BUCKETS;
    bucket_entry *e = (bucket_entry *) malloc(sizeof(bucket_entry));
    if (!e) panic("No memory to allocate bucket!");
    e->next = table[i];
    e->key = key;
    e->val = val;
    table[i] = e;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Retrieves an entry from the hash table by key
// Returns NULL if the key isn't found in the table
bucket_entry * retrieve(int key) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    bucket_entry *b;
    for (b = table[key % NUM_BUCKETS]; b != NULL; b = b->next) {
        if (b->key == key) return b;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

So the main problems here are:

1. How to tell where data is being lost between each thread operation
2. What could cause the program to hang when the keys are being retrieved from the hashtable?

Comment: You *can't* tell when a thread will be preemted, which is why you use locks to protect common resources. By the way, the `insert` function, is that the whole thread function? Is that all the tread does? It doesn't seem very useful for a thread.

Comment: If `retrieve()` finds a matching key, it returns the object without releasing the lock. If it doesn't find the key it exits the thread. Bizarre.

Comment: Your program hangs because you don't unlock the mutex when you return a successful hit. But why do you do pthread_exit in both functions? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should read more about [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Read also [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). Notice in particular that every locking call like [pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) should *always* be later followed by a call to [pthread_mutex_unlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_mutex_unlock.html) on the *same* mutex (and *conventionally* you should adopt the *discipline* that each lock and unlock happens in the *same* block). Hence your `return` in the `for` loop of your `retrieve`  is wrong, you should code:

```
bucket_entry * 
retrieve(int key) {
  bucket_entry *res = NULL;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  for (bucket_entry *b = table[key % NUM_BUCKETS]; 
       b != NULL; b = b->next) {
     if (b->key == key) 
        { res = b; break; };
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  return res;
}
```

Then you could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and use a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. [5.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) in November 2015). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread`). Read about the sanitizer [debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), in particular consider using `-fsanitize=thread`

There are few reasons to call `pthread_exit` (likewise, you *rarely* call `exit` in a program). When you do, the entire current thread will be terminated.